# GuardDuty tells me private instances are being probed by hosts on the internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, guardduty

This is weird, I'm having some instances running in a private subnet. Those subnets are not exposed to the Internet directly, they don't have a public IP and all outgoing traffic is routed through a NAT instance.

However, GuardDuty gives me warnings like this for all instances in this private subnet:

```
Recon:EC2/PortProbeUnprotectedPort
Action
Action type
PORT_PROBE


Blocked
false
First seen
12-21-2019 22:22:10 (a month ago)
Last seen
01-19-2020 11:18:12 (38 minutes ago)
Actor
IP address
159.65.11.106
Location
country:
Singapore
lat:
1.314
lon:
103.6839
Organization
asn:
14061
asnOrg:
DigitalOcean, LLC
isp:
Digital Ocean
org:
Digital Ocean

Additional information
Threat name
Scanner
Threat list name
ProofPoint
Local port
30539
Archived
false
Remote IP details
ipAddress:
5.101.0.209
location:
Moscow, Russia
organization:
PinSPB
```

So, multiple questions arise here:

- How is it even possible my instance gets scanned when it doesn't have a public IP adres?
- Why is the actor IP address different from the remote IP?

Answer (score 4):

I think I might have found the reason myself, and I'll post it as an answer in case other people come accross this issue as well:

Those instances were part of a Kubernetes cluster, and I use nginx as the ingress controller. This ingress controller is exposed via `type:Loadbalancer` and with an annotation that causes AWS to use a Network LoadBalancer (NLB).

Since NLB's preserve the origin IP address, those IP's are also shown in the AWS GuardDuty logs.

Comment: This is happening to me too. Though, the ports that are being probed are not listening in the nlb. For example, port 32001. I have it opened on the security group, my eks ec2 instance is private, the eks endpoints are private, the nlb has only listeners for 80 and 443 but I'm still getting EC2/PortProbeUnprotectedPort on port 32001. When you experienced what you described you had those ports listening on nlb? Thanks.